# How to query for multiple records using SQL using 'String Interpolation' that's specific to the 'pg' module Postgres

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql

I have four tables: `brands`, `countries`, `packaging_styles`, `reviews`

**The requirement is:**
Write a function to find reviews for *a set of brands*.

> NOTE1: The brands param is an array of strings - Array of brands. 
> NOTE2: The function should return an array of review object that match the given brands.

###### The query itself is tested in Postico application and it works as it should be

```js
const getByBrands = async (brands = []) => {
  const review = await pool.query('SELECT b.brand "Brand", c.country "country",\
  r.id "ID", r.stars "Stars",\
  s.packaging_style "Style",\
  r.url "URL", r.variety "Variety"\
  FROM brands b, countries c, reviews r, packaging_styles s\
  WHERE r.brand_id = b.id\
  AND b.brand IN ($1, $2, $3)', brands);
  return review.rows;
};
getByBrands(['Koka', 'Boss', 'Peyang']);
```

Now what I am stuck at is I can only get records for three brands as opposed to as much as I want

Comment: You need to use `ANY` instead of `IN` to compare to an array. I don't know exactly how it would be in javascript but in postgres/SQL it should end up looking like this: `AND b.brand = ANY(['Koka', 'Boss', 'Peyang'])`. Ideally you should be able to mark the array param as `ANY($1)` and have the array be placed in there, so it will work with an array of any size.

Comment: I think my issue is more of js than sql.

Comment: @404. the link helped indeed and it fixed the issue. Thanks a lot. Please have a look of how I did it and confirm. This may be useful for someone else later.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed the problem

```js
const getByBrands = async (brands = []) => {
  const review = await pool.query('SELECT b.brand "Brand", c.country "country",\
  r.id "ID", r.stars "Stars",\
  s.packaging_style "Style",\
  r.url "URL", r.variety "Variety"\
  FROM brands b, countries c, reviews r, packaging_styles s\
  WHERE r.brand_id = b.id\
  AND b.brand = ANY ($1::text[])', [brands]);
  console.log(review.rows);
  return review.rows;
};
getByBrands(['Koka','Boss']);
```